# Elastic collision of waves?

Tags: waves

In classical theory, particles are similar to little, hard balls, that can scatter off each other in elastic collision. Waves, on the other hand, can pass through each other unaltered, although they will interfere. Is there any situation in which waves, eg sound waves, can interfere in such a way that the outcome if as if they have scattered elastically off each other?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, waves can scatter off each other when they are propagating in a nonlinear medium: a medium in which the propagation speed depends on the wave amplitude.  *Elastic* scattering is perhaps a different issue: if the waves are changed after their interaction, it is not appropriate to call it elastic scattering; and it is not at all unusual for the waves to be transformed dramatically in nonlinear interactions.
A good resource is:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics.

Comment: That is really interesting - thank you.